# How to convert Excel Cells for Datazen?

Tags: sql-server, excel, business-intelligence, data-import, datazen-server

To learn Datazen i begin with excel tables but I've some problems.

I have a name column and a value column like this:

[image: tableData]

But when i import it into datazen the data become:

[image: datazentable]

And Datazen doesn't recognized data as string and it's not possible to create a chart with names column. I've tried to change the format cell into text but there's no effects, someone can help me? thanks

Comment: Try to change cell type for first column as `Date` and the second column as `Number`.

Comment: Not work, note that it works if I add a row with a column ('AAA', '0') but it changes the name into '201' instead of '02.01'

Comment: Try putting a column name into the first row (above NOMS / ID)

Comment: Same problem, i have changed the '.' into '_' and it works, i think there is no solution to use this format into string with Excel files( with a SSAS connection, I can change the format for each column ).